# what is the difference in using page object model insted of using page factory for the locators?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

i am tring to figure out what is the effort of using the POM over the POF at the timing and at the locators way (i know it's different in the locators using) also in POM i'm using the By so what is the difference more than the writtening, i mean at the using or time or locating elements, so why its recomanded to avoid the POF?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer :**

Without **Page Factory** support, POM would lose advantage of having below mentioned features in framework as **Page Factory** is **Enhanced POM** which would provide key features during framework design & development.

**Long Answer :**

2 Things To Understand : **Page Object Model (POM) & Enhanced POM i.e. Page Factory**

**Page Object Model (POM):** It's an object design pattern in Selenium, where web pages are represented as classes, and the various elements on the page are defined as variables on the class. All possible user interactions can then be implemented as methods on the classes.

In order to support **Page Object** model, we use **Page Factory**. Page Factory in Selenium is an extension to Page Object and can be used in various ways. Some examples below -

***Note - If we use POM without Page Factory then we would not be having advantages of below features in our framework.***

1. We can use **Page Factory** to initialize web elements that are defined in web page classes or Page Objects.
2. We can use AjaxElementLocatorFactory in Page Factory which uses an Explicit Wait & it will wait up to N No. of seconds for each element **ANYTIME** they are accessed.
3. Annotation **@CacheLookup** in Factory, when we know that some elements are always going to be there on the page, then it make sense to cache. For example, on Google page, search button is on search and results both pages, so element to locate search button can be cached

Comment: and what is the disadvantages?
cause as far as i know 
Simon Stewart, Selenium project lead and creator of the **Page Factory**, at the 2017 SeleniumConf in Austin. During his keynote address he says not to use Page Factory. This section of the talk starts here:

https://youtu.be/gyfUpOysIF8?t=1517

Actual statement is at 27:25.

i didn't understand why, but there is something in that.

also, explicit wait can also be used with POM with wait.until, so what's than? (even better than the implicit wait)

Comment: It's not we shall not use Page Factory rather point is we shall take care of few things like we shall not declare web element as static in that situation we lose the advantage of page factory concepts. There have been multiple projects where Page Factory is used even I have been using Page Factory for last one year and I find no issue in the framework. We get stable outcome. Thing is it's all about how do we implement Page Factory in a framework.

Comment: and that that at the POF Elements are identified using '@FindBy or @FindBys' Annotation and Initialism all the elements declared at the identification time (PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);.
in POM, initialization happens on the fly (so there is difference if something wasnt at the start for example)